# Является ли композитный файл нарушением принципа единственной обязанности

Tags: java, ооп, кэширование, repository, solid

Приведу пару примеров реализации репозитория с кэшем:

Пример 1:

```
// две обязанности, получить данные и кэшировать
class Repository {
  private final Cache cache;
  private final Api api;
  ........
  Data getData(int arg) {
    if (cache.containsData(arg))
      return cache.getData(data);

    Data data = api.getData();
    cache.putData(data, arg);
    return data;
  }
}
```

Пример 2:

```
// одна обязанность, получить данные
class Repository {
  private final Api api;

  ..............

  Data getData(int arg) {  
    return api.getData();
  }
}

// одна обязанность кэшировать данные
// или две? получить с другого репозитория и кэшировать
class CachedRepository {
  private final Cache cache;
  private final Repository next;
  ........
  Data getData(int arg) {
    if (cache.containsData(arg))
      return cache.getData(data);

    Data data = next.getData(arg);
    cache.putData(data, arg);
    return data;
  }
}
```

Помогите разобраться с кашей в голове.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галочка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

Да, репозиторий и кэширование - это две обязанности. Однако, в вашем втором примере кэширующий репозиторий - это [прокси](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)) к простому репозиторию (надо бы их еще объединить общим интерфейсом), и вот тут уже SRP не нарушается.

Под *ответственностью* в SRP Мартин подразумевал необходимость внесения изменения в класс - причина возникновения такой необходимости должна быть одна. Во втором примере у класса будет как раз только одна причина для изменения - изменение алгоритма/метода кэширования. Если изменится реализация репозитория (смена БД, nosql, фейковый репозиторий в памяти для юнит-тестов и т.д.) это никак не повлияет на класс кэширования.

---

Класс, организующий взаимодействие двух классов (т.е. [фасад](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B4_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F))) [не нарушает SRP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17807770/does-the-facade-pattern-violate-srp). Под ответственностью в этом случае будет подразумеваться логика взаимодействия между классами.

Comment: В первом варианте тоже одна причина. Смена концепции. Т.к. за получение данных отвечает какой-то абстрактный класс, и за кэширование тоже. Концепцией репозитория является обработка этих двух классов. До тех пор пока я не парился всей этой ерундой, писал нормальные приложения. )))

Comment: @АлексейМальченко понял, если Cache и Data абстрактные, и как-то передаются зависимостями в класс, то тогда, конечно, нет нарушения. Я почему-то думал, что у вас там прямо в классе логика работы с источником данных и кэширования зашита.

Comment: В некоторых источниках говорится, что это всеравно несколько обязанностей у класса, неявно. Или пока нет конкретики, то обязанностью является координирование работы этих 2х классов?

Comment: @АлексейМальченко после изменений вопроса: второй пример имеет смысл, если есть несколько разных API - сторонних библиотек, которые мы не можем менять, и все их нужно использовать. Тогда унифицируем все API в виде репозиториев и используем. Если же API уже абстрактный и не привязан к конкретному источнику данных, то первый пример от второго не отличается.

Comment: Спасибо, впринципе как-то так я и думал. Просто не с кем посоветоваться.

Comment: @АлексейМальченко насчет координации работы двух классов интересный вопрос. Вот [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17807770/does-the-facade-pattern-violate-srp) пишут, что не это не нарушает SRP, поскольку ответственностью будет являться только координация.